# Redirect to an invitation link after login/signup in React

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm building a fantasy sports app. Users can create a league and if successful are given an invitation link to share with other people. All routes except for the login and signup page are inaccessible if a user isn't logged in so when someone uses the invitation link it sends them to the login page.

How do I save the invitation link so when they login/signup they can be taken back to it?

I've tried using `document.referrer` but it gives me 'localhost:3000' instead of 'localhost:3000/invite/:leagueid.
I'm using react router and just read that `<Redirect />` can override the current history so I've also tried pushing state to the window history. I've tried calling a function at the top level of my app that looks if `window.location.origin` includes "invite" and if so save that url in state so i can redirect after a successful login but it is never triggered.

Here is some of my top level component:

```js
const App = observer(() => {
  const store = useStore();
  const loggedIn = store.loggedIn;

    return (
      <div>
        <>
          {!loggedIn ?
          <Redirect to="/login" /> 
          : 
          <NavBar />}
        </>
        <SomeRoutes />
      </div>
      
    );
 }
```

And here are functions in my store (using MobX) to get the invitation link:

```js
    getReferrer() {
        if (!this.loggedIn && this.fromInvite) {
            this.referrer = window.location.origin;
        } else {
            this.referrer = '';
        }
    }
    
    get fromInvite() {return !!window.location.origin.includes("invite")}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it figured out.

The reason why nothing was happening was that my logIn function is asynchronous but I didn't have async/await in my onClick submit handler in my logIn component. After I added that I was able to redirect back to the previous page after a successful login. Completely unrelated to what I thought the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Use [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/28c89f4091ae9e1b0001341ea60c629674e83627/docs/getting-started.md) to redirect. Use `push` method: `history.push(localhost:3000/invite/leadueid-1` (leagueid-1 is just for example).

Comment: I've tried using history and the history hook as well. I guess the problem is that I can't save the invitation url once it redirects to the login page.

Comment: Try using `localStorage` for it

Comment: Thanks for your help but it still can't find the url i'm looking for despite it sending me to my app. Gonna try to change my router a bit and see if that helps; I feel like I should be able to send it within my <Redirect />.